# Omniauth session lost during authentication

Tags: mongoid, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm working on an application which uses Discord OAuth as a authentication method. Because this app needs a Discord account to have, I just use omniauth-discord, and not any local authentication methodology.
But during the authentication after the Discord callback I loose the session. The user will be created in the MongoDB, but after that, the current_user will give back a `nil` value.

I can call the Discord OAuth without any issues, and get the information from the callback, store in the MongoDB, but than if I try to authorize the user to use the site, there isn't an available session, so the logininfo will give back 401 every time. If I try to sign in again, I always get the Discord consent page.
I've already tried many different codes from tutorials, but most of them uses Devise for local login, and authentication, then connect the local user with the Discord one.
Also tried to init the session in very different part of the code, without any luck.

I've created a github repo for the current situation of the code. You can find it here:
https://github.com/montyx99/ppapi

My sessions_contoller.rb:

```rb
require 'json'

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        redirect_to '/auth/discord'
    end

    def current_user
        super
    end

    def create
        session[:init] = true
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        user = User.where(:discord_id => auth.extra.raw_info.id).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
        p user
        p user.discord_id
        # Reset the session after successful login, per
        # 2.8 Session Fixation – Countermeasures:
        # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures
        reset_session
        session[:user_id] = user.discord_id
        p session[:user_id]
        redirect_to "http://localhost:3000", :notice => 'Signed in!'
    end

    def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to "http://localhost:3000", :notice => 'Signed out!'
    end

    def failure
        redirect_to "http://localhost:3000", :alert => "Authentication error: #{params[:message].humanize}"
    end

    def logininfo
        p current_user
        if current_user
            render :json => true, :status => 200
        else
            render :json => false, :status => 401
        end
    end
end
```

The application_controller.rb

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    def current_user
        begin
            @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
        rescue Exception => e
            nil
        end
    end

    def user_signed_in?
        return true if current_user
    end

    def correct_user?
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        unless current_user == @user
            redirect_to root_url, :alert => "Access denied."
        end
    end

    def authenticate_user!
        if !current_user
            redirect_to root_url, :alert => 'You need to sign in for access to this page.'
        end
    end


    def logging
        id = ENV["DISCORD_CLIENT_ID"]
        secret = ENV["DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    end
end
```

Expected:

After the first handshake with Discord, the user need to be able to login again next time without the Discord Consent page

Comment: rescue Exception => e
            nil

The line which this rescue block applies to should not be raising  exceptions as far as I can see. Remove this rescue and diagnose the exceptions being raised there, if any.

Comment: Thank you @OlegP I'm going to check it

Answer (score 0):

At first You’re assigning the discord_id as your user ID in `session[:user_id]`. Then when you call `User.find` in `current_user`, you’re not then searching against your discord_id user property, find will search by user.id by default. Your actual user.id is probably an Integer assigned by the database.

Also your begin is redundant in current_user. Take it out and the first end and indent back. Begin at the start of a method is implied so you only need to rescue before you end.

Comment: Also current_user in SessionsController is redundant too.